# Searching for terms with underscore doesn't return expected results

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

How can I search a documents named "Hola-Mundo_Army.jpg" searching by the Army* word (always using the asterisk key at the end please)? The thing is that if I search the documents using Army* the result is zero. I think that the problem is the underscore before Army word.

But if I search Mundo_Army* the result is one found, correctly.

`docs?api-version=2016-09-01&search=Mundo_Army*` <--- 1 result OK
`docs?api-version=2016-09-01&search=Army*` <--- 0 results and it should find 1 result like the previous search. I always need to use the asterisk at the end.

Thank you!

This is the blob information that I have to search and find:

```
{
            "@search.score": 1,
            "content": "{\"azure_cdn\":\"http:\\/\\/dev-dr-documents.azureedge.net\\/localhost-hugo-docs-not-indexed\\/Hola-Mundo_Army.jpg\"}\n",
            "source": "dr",
            "title": "Hola-Mundo_Army.jpg",
            "file_name": "Hola-Mundo_Army.jpg",
            "file_type": "Image",
            "year_created": "2017",
            "client": "LALALA",
            "brand": "LELELE",
            "description": "HUGO_DEV-TUCUMAN",
            "categories": "Clothing and Accessories",
            "media": "Online media",
            "tags": null,
            "channel": "Case Study",
            "azuresearch_skipcontent": "1",
            "id": "1683",
            "metadata_storage_content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "metadata_storage_size": 109,
            "metadata_storage_last_modified": "2017-04-26T18:30:35Z",
            "metadata_storage_content_md5": "o2yZWelvS/EAukoOhCuuKg==",
            "metadata_storage_name": "Hola-Mundo_Army.json",
            "metadata_content_encoding": "ISO-8859-1",
            "metadata_content_type": "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            "metadata_language": "en"
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to troubleshoot cases like this is by using the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer). It will help you understand how your documents and query terms are processed by the search engine. In your case, assuming you are not setting the analyzer property on the field you are searching against, the text *Hola-Mundo_Army.jpg* is broken down by the default analyzer into the following two terms: *hola, mundo_army.jpg.* These are the terms that are in your index. That's why, when you are searching for the prefix *mundo_army**, the term *mundo_army.jpg* is matched. Prefix *army** doesn't match anything in your index.

You can learn more about the the default behavior of the search engine and how to customize it from this article: [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture)